# How can I get the equations of motion used in webots?

Tags: mobile-robot, webots

I am trying to use the webots platform for developing controllers. I need the differential equations governing the motion of the robots. How can I get the equations of motion used in webots?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** the below mention function does not export equations directly, as you requested, but exports the dynamic system in the DIF - Dynamics Interchange Format

Webots uses the Open Dynamics Engine (ODE) to simulate physics. ODE includes an export [function for exporting the ODE](http://opende.sourceforge.net/docs/export-dif_8h_source.html) called `dWorldExportDIF()`.

Webots seems to support this export function and it also includes a test, which uses the function mentioned above to export the equations. The test, which exports the equations can be found here:
https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots/blob/master/tests/physics/plugins/physics/ode_dif_exporter/ode_dif_exporter.c